# How to Reduce iteration of switch syntax

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have two variable clickDay and clickDay1 and if I write a code with two switch syntax, it works fine. But I don't know how can I reduce to one switch syntax.

Here's my original code

```
let day;
        let day1;
        switch (clickDay) {
            case 'monday':
                day = 'mon';
                break;
            case 'Tuesday':
                day = 'tue';
                break;
            case 'Wednesday':
                day = 'wed';
                break;
            case 'Thursday':
                day = 'tur';
                break;
            case 'Friday':
                day = 'fri';
                break;
        }
        switch (clickDay1) {
            case 'monday':
                day = 'mon';
                break;
            case 'Tuesday':
                day = 'tue';
                break;
            case 'Wednesday':
                day = 'wed';
                break;
            case 'Thursday':
                day = 'tur';
                break;
            case 'Friday':
                day = 'fri';
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an object whose keys are the full day, and values are the abbreviated version. Then, to determine both `day` and `day1`, simply look up the `clickDay` or the `clickDay1` on the object:

```
const days = {
  monday: 'mon', // should the "m" be capitalized?
  Tuesday: 'tue',
  Wednesday: 'wed',
  Thursday: 'tur', // should this be `thu`?
  Friday: 'fri',
};

const day = days[clickDay];
const day1 = days[clickDay1];
```

Note that this will assign `undefined` to `day` or `day1` if the `clickDay` or `clickDay1` variable does not contain one of the full day names in the object.

If you *had* to use the verbose `switch` statement for whatever reason (not recommended), you would have to put it inside a function:

```
function getDay(fullDay) {
  let day;
  switch (fullDay) {
    case 'monday':
      day = 'mon';
      break;
    case 'Tuesday':
      day = 'tue';
      break;
    case 'Wednesday':
      day = 'wed';
      break;
    case 'Thursday':
      day = 'tur';
      break;
    case 'Friday':
      day = 'fri';
      break;
  }
  return day;
}
const day = getDay(clickDay);
const day1 = getDay(clickDay1);
```

But an object is a better choice than `switch` 99% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like (assuming `tur` is a typo) that all your days are just the first three letters lower case:

So you could just use:

```
let day = clickDay.slice(0,3).toLowerCase()
```

and be done with it. This assumes you know `clickDay` will be a valid day of the week.

```js
let days = [
  "Monday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday",
  "Thursday",
  "Friday",
  "Saturday",
  "Sunday"
]

days.forEach(clickDay => console.log(clickDay.slice(0,3).toLowerCase()))
```

Answer (score 0):

To reduce it to one switch, use a function. Send `clickDay` or `clickDay1` as a parameter and expect the result to be returned.

```
function abreviate(day) {
    switch (day) {
        case 'monday':
            return 'mon';
        case 'Tuesday':
            return 'tue';
        case 'Wednesday':
            return 'wed';
        case 'Thursday':
            return 'tur';
        case 'Friday':
            return 'fri';
    }
}

let day = abreviate(clickDay);
let day1 = abreviate(clickDay1);
```

Take in consideration that the switch statement does not have a `default`. This will result in `undefined` if nothing else is returned.